# Refresh MVC Partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I want to refresh a partial view in every 30 seconds.

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Inbox</h2>

@Html.Partial("_Inbox")
```

this is my partial view

```
@model IList<Empite.Echo.Repository.Query.SubscriberMessageResult>

<table>
@foreach (var message in Model)
{
<tr>
    <td>@message.Message</td>
    <td>@message.IsRead</td>
    <td>@message.MessageGuid</td>
</tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: Your question is so brief that it's very hard to answer. There are plenty of methods, so it wouldn't help listing all of them here. What behavior do you expect? What methods did you try and why didn't they work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your partial in a div container

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Inbox</h2>
<div id="partialContainer">
   @Html.Partial("_Inbox")
</div>
```

You'll then need to create an action on your controller that returns a [PartialViewResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.partialviewresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) For instance,

```
public ActionResult ActionThatReturnsPartialResult(){
    return Partial();
}
```

Then refresh using JavaScript

```
setInterval(function(){
 $('#partialContainer').load('@Url.Action("ActionThatReturnsPartialResult","SomeController")' + '?id=' + id+ '&status=' + status);
}, 30000);
```

If you want to pass a model to the Partial controller you can do so by using the data overload for the jQuery [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method

Answer (score 0):

try code

Loanpartial is Div

Account: Controller

Register is View and Action

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
             refr();
 });`     

 function refr() {      
    var intervalss = setInterval(refnew, 30000);
    function refnew() {
        $("#Loanpartial").load("/Account/Register");
    }
}
```